# Asp classic unterminated string constant

Tags: apache, iis, soap, vbscript, asp-classic

I was looking in the web for a way to consume a SOAP API with ASP classic, and i found something like this code:

```
<%

Response.Write "<br>START<hr>"

Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", "URL Web Service", False 

SOAPRequest = _
  "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:aut=""URL.xsd"">"&_
    "<soap:Header/>" &_
    "<soap12:Body>" &_
        "<aut:authorize>" &_
        "<sessionToken>" &_ "SessionToken" &_ "</sessionToken>" &_
        "<appId>appMobileDesa</appId>" &_
        "<resource>/serviclub</resource>" &_
        "<action>GET</action>" &_
      "</aut:authorize>" &_
    "</soap:Body>" &_
  "</soap:Envelope>"

oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:Authorize"" 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(SOAPRequest)
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host", "URL:80"
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep-Alive"  

oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest  

Response.Write oXmlHTTP.responseText

Response.Write "<br>END<hr>"
%>
```

I've replaced the real URLs and the Session Token with words.
Basicly it's a page that calls an API to request authorization.
But i keep getting error 500 when i call the asp page.
When i looked into the logs, i've found this:

```
2018-04-27 18:19:17 10.5.42.121 GET /login/mobileYPF/autorizacion.asp |9|800a0409|Unterminated_string_constant 8080 - 10.5.42.121 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 500 0 0 49
```

Any ideas about how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line contains the unterminated string constant: `oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:Authorize""`

If yo'ure trying to have `urn:Authorize` be wrapped in quotes, it needs to be like this:

`oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""urn:Authorize"""` <- note the closing `"`

(Also, `"<sessionToken>" &_ "SessionToken" &_ "</sessionToken>" &_` is not valid syntax.

It should be `"<sessionToken>" & "SessionToken" & "</sessionToken>" &_`. The `_` is not needed if you're on the same line. I realize this may be an edited section for this post.)

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you very much!